# make jQuery animation queue unresponsive to clicks

Tags: jquery, animation

No matter what I do, I can't get this chain of animations to be unaffected by a click whilst it's running. I've tried placing `.stop` before each `.animate` (trying different combinations of 'true'/'false' for the Booleans)  but that doesn't have the desired effect.

Ideally the animation will be completely unresponsive to clicks until the queue/chain has completed.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.title-bar, #menu-wrap').click(function () {
            if ($('#menu-wrap').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
                $('#menu-wrap').animate({top : '-170px'}, 1000);    
                $('.nav').slideToggle(1400);       
                $('.lower').css('background-image', 'none');
            } else {
                $('#menu-wrap').offset().top = 0;     
                $('#menu-wrap').animate({top : '0px'}, 1000); 
                $('.nav').slideToggle(600);
                $('.lower').css({'background-image' : 'url(menu2.png)', 'background-position' : 'bottom center'});
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Hope you can help

Comment: unbind the click event handler at the top of the function, and when your last animation completes, rebind it.

Comment: I think because i've gone for the slightly awkward choice of positioning my menu off-screen, animating it vertically downwards AND combining a `.slideToggle` there is an issue with positioning if the `.slideToggle` hasn't completed when the user clicks again - i.e. it's offset. Unbinding will work to disable clicks, but I need to try and let the animations finish completely before rebinding the click. At the moment, if I rebind the click at the end of the queue, there is an interruption. I should explain that I have an aesthetic and design reason for combining `.animation` and `.slideToggle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code using the `$(elem).is(':animated')` syntax for checking if an element is being animated. Ex:

```
if ( !$(this).is(':animated') ) ...
```

Updated example:

```
    $('.title-bar, #menu-wrap').click(function () {
        if ( !$(this).is(':animated') ) {
        if ($('#menu-wrap').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
            $('#menu-wrap').animate({top : '-170px'}, 1000);    
            $('.nav').slideToggle(1400);       
            $('.lower').css('background-image', 'none');
        } else {
            $('#menu-wrap').offset().top = 0;     
            $('#menu-wrap').animate({top : '0px'}, 1000); 
            $('.nav').slideToggle(600);
            $('.lower').css({'background-image' : 'url(menu2.png)', 'background-position' : 'bottom center'});
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So I'd essentially unbind clicks if it's animating, else if do nothing?

Comment: No unbinding needed here. By wrapping your code with this you'd only run it if no animation was occurring.

Comment: j08691 - I think I need a little help. Could you give me an example of how I'd adjust my code for this?

Comment: Hey, this worked well - although I had to disable the secondary 'active' click area. After I'd done that, this worked a treat and seems to render any clicks inactive during the animation queue. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

there is property called queue which will help you. I think this should help... the way it looks, you should write a callback function which will be called after other function has been complete.

Comment: I should probably tell you that I've yet to go through using `.queue` but am reading up about it now. In the meantime if there's a workaround I'd be happy with that!

Comment: hey gimme5. can you explain, I think what you are trying to achieve is do something on click happens using if in between. this looks correct what is problem I am not able to understand it thoroughly. I think you use call back function in animate function itself. only after animation is complete slideToggle(or whatever you are doing)

Comment: Hey Dhruvenkumar, it seems that the mixing of two different animations and the time it took the queue to complete was the problem. The solution above seemed to fix the problem for me though.

Comment: okay I which solution, posted by whom, currently I am not at all in touch with jquery but hope your prob. is solved using SO.com..